# Static resource protection issue in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to protect my static resource as below in MobileFirst Platform.

```
<resource id="webStaticResources" securityTest="webStaticSecurityTest">
<urlPatterns>/default/views*</urlPatterns>
</resource>
```

"**views**" is a folder in my application that contains .html files.
  I tried **/views*** also.

Now the problem is, it is blocking every url including /worklightconsole and giving me error 404. Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "application"? Your **mobile app**?

Answer (score 0):

The authenticationConfig.xml file is meant for server resources and not application resources. You cannot use it in this manner in order to protect your application.

To protect your application, use the MobileFirst security framework: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/